# Odd behavior adding RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have the following rule:

```
  RewriteRule ^(image/[0-9]*/(.*))?$ image.php?prettyUrl=true&nav=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This is supposed to replace

```
  http://mysite.com/image/12345/imagename.png => http://mysite.com/image.php?pretyUrl=true&nav=image/12345/imagename.png
```

For the particular case where the pretty url contains '/image/' the $_GET array is empty. If I use a different name like 'images' or 'asdfg' the $_GET array will contain both pretyUrl and nav.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Post some example url for your particular case `/image`

Comment: Is this a 90 percent regex problem? Its too bad people don't know enough about regular expressions to isolate thier problems. I solated, specifically written, can get an exact answer in 10 seconds. Just a FYI.

Comment: Its probably not a regex problem, in which case don't add the regex tag next time. hey

Comment: Is this rule in an `.htaccess` file? If so, in which directory is it located?

Answer (score 0):

If the rewrite rule must work for every URL in `image/`, (and the `/1234/` digits part is not required), then this may be what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^(image(/.*)?)$ image.php?prettyUrl=true&nav=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you can phrase your question a bit more specifically, a better solution can be refined.